# Tentando construir um grafo

Tags: c, grafo

Bom pessoal, suponho que meu problema seja bem simples, mas estou com dificuldade, se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço!

O que eu quero é o seguinte: criar um vetor que consiga alocar vários caracteres referentes a um grafo, tipo vetor vertex[A,B,C,D,...,AXZ]

e farei depois o mesmo para as arestas tipo arestas edge[(A,B),(C,B),(A,AZ),...,(AZS,AZZ)] e coisa do tipo.

mas na hora que estava debugando passei o valor inteiro V para inticar o tamanho do vetor, mas na hora que passa para a função, o valor 5 passa a ser 79 e aí bagunça

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//esta função constrói os vértices do grafo
char graph_vertex(){
    int k;
    char *vertex;
    //variável para pegar a quantidade de vértices presentes no grafo em questão
    int vertice;
    //iniciando a variável
    k=0;
    //da começo à construção do vértice, a partir da aquisição da quantidade de vértices pertencentes ao grafo
    printf("Quantos vértices o grafo possui?\n");
    scanf("%d",&vertice);
    //cria a variável vertex para alocar os vértices do grafo
    vertex = (char*)malloc(vertice * sizeof(char)); 
    //aquisição de vértices
    printf("Digite os vértices pertencentes ao grafo.\n" );
    printf("Obs.: o grafo pode ser constituído por letras ou números. \n" );
    //entra num loop a fim de capturar todos os vértices
    while(vertice != k){
        //o caracter em questão é gravado na variável vertex
        scanf(" %c",&vertex[k]);
        //esta condição verifica se o caracter digitado é uma letra
        if (isalpha(vertex[k]))
        {
            //caso seja uma letra, esta mesma será convertida para letra maiúscula
            vertex[k] = toupper(vertex[k]);
            k++;
        }else{      
            k++;
        }       
    }
    //impressão do vetor [vertex]
    int i =0;
    while(vertice != i){
        printf("\n");
        printf("%c \n", vertex[i]);
        i++;
    }
}


int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    //chama a função responsável pelo vértice
    graph_vertex();
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: eu fiz as alterações, mas por algum, se eu coloco o tamanho da quantia de vértices 5, ele le apenas dois vértices e faz a impressão de 5 números. acredito que seja referente ao número do tamanho do vértice

Comment: Editei o meu comentário pra responder esse problema :)

Comment: CONSEGUI resolver, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você declarou `V` como um `int` mas leu ele como um `long`, o correto seria ler como um inteiro (`scanf("%d", &V)`) ou declarar V como um long (`long V;`)

Um outro ponto, você provavelmente vai ter problemas como [segmentation fault](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falha_de_segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o) por utilizar um parâmetro para definir o tamanho do vetor `vertex`. Ao invés de utilizar `char vertex[n];` utilize o [malloc](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html), da seguinte maneira:

```c
char *vertex = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

No momento de leitura, como você está trabalhando com char, ele acaba lendo espaços e quebras de linha também, então você precisa ignorar eles:

```c
scanf(" %c", &vertex[k]); // foi adicionado um espaço antes do %c
```

No momento do print também tem um errinho. Você está querendo imprimir o valor do vetor em determinada posição, não o seu endereço, então você não precisa usar o "&":

```c
printf("%c\n", vertex[k]);
```

PS: Ao terminar de utilizar o vetor, não esqueça de desalocar a memória utilizando `free(vertex)`